# Enviar una variable de un Activity a una Clase

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

tengo una app que estoy desarrollando y necesito enviar una variable desde mi activity al Repo de mi RecyclerView de tipo class, para usarlo en un whereEqualTo de Firebase. Necesito ayuda porque no consigo como lograrlo.

Este es el codigo de mi Repo de tipo class

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.ui.RecyMenu

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class RepoMenu {

    fun getTiendaData(): LiveData<MutableList<Plato>> {
        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Plato>>()
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Platos").whereEqualTo("tienda", "AquiVaMiVariable").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                mutableData.value = result.documents.map { snap ->
                    snap.run {
                        Plato(
                            getString("plato") ?: "default",
                            getString("descripcion") ?: "default",
                            getBoolean("stock") ?: false,
                            getString("precio") ?: "default",
                        )
                    }
                }.toMutableList()
            }


        return mutableData
    }


}
```

La variable la usare para filtrar los elementos que necesito con el whereEqualTo.

Y este es mi activity

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.ui.RecyMenu.MyAdapterMenu
import com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.ui.RecyMenu.MyViewModelMenu
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_pedir.*


class PedirActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyAdapterMenu.OnTiendaListener {

    private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapterMenu
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModelMenu::class.java)}


    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedir)

        var nombreTienda = intent.getStringExtra("nombreTienda") //Este es la variable que necesito enviar
        var tiendaEmail = intent.getStringExtra("emailTienda")


        title = "Menu de $nombreTienda"

        adapter = MyAdapterMenu(this, this)

        recyclerViewMenu.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerViewMenu.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
        recyclerViewMenu.adapter = adapter
        observeData()


    }

    fun observeData(){
        viewModel.fetchTiendaData().observe(this, Observer {

            adapter.setListData(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        })
    }

    override fun onItemClick(nombre: String) {



    }

}
```

La variable que necesito enviar es la que dice nombreTienda.

Bueno es seria todo, no se si tenga que compartir los demas codigos que estan en mi RecyclerView como mi Adapter o mi ViewModel, si es necesario para que me ayuden me dicen y los agrego.

edit: Aqui agrego el viewModel

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.ui.RecyMenu

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MyViewModelMenu: ViewModel() {

    val repo = RepoMenu()

    fun fetchTiendaData():LiveData<MutableList<Plato>>{

        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Plato>>()
        repo.getTiendaData().observeForever {
            mutableData.value = it
        }

        return mutableData

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías agregarle un parámetro a la función y pasarla como argumento

```
fun getTiendaData(tienda: String): LiveData<MutableList<Plato>> {
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Plato>>()
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Platos").whereEqualTo("tienda", tienda).get()
    ...
}
```

Por supuesto también tendrás que agregarle el parámetro a las funciones intermediarias. Por ejemplo, la función en tu viewModel podría reducirse a esto

```
fun fetchTiendaData(tienda: String) = repo.getTiendaData(tienda)
```

Finalmente en la activity pasas la variable a la función `observeData()` y ésta se encargará de pasarla al viewModel donde finalmente será enviada al repositorio.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    var nombreTienda = intent.getStringExtra("nombreTienda")
    ...
    observeData(nombreTienda)
}

fun observeData(tienda: String){
    viewModel.fetchTiendaData(tienda).observe(this, Observer {
        adapter.setListData(it)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, le agregue un if para verificar que la variable no sea nula